# Выгрузка Assembly

Tags: c#, assembly

```
public static AppDomain tss;

public void LoadBackground()
{
    this.tss = AppDomain.CreateDomain("test");
    byte[] but = File.ReadAllBytes("TestGUI.dll");
    Type type = this.tss.Load(but).GetType("TestGUI.Class1");
    MethodInfo myMethod = type.GetMethod("Init");
    object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    if (myMethod != null)
    {
        myMethod.Invoke(obj, null);
    }
}
```

но если вызываю `AppDomain.Unload(MainMenu.tss);` из TestGUI, то получаю ошибку

> Parament name : domain Argument can't null

Хотя dll работает

Comment: А из какого домена вы вызываете это?

Comment: @VladD кого его? tss.load это домен test

Comment: Да, это я понял. Но вот этот код с AppDomain.Unload вы запускаете в каком AppDomain’е?

Comment: @VladD ну получается в основном - вот так AppDomain.Unload(tss);

Comment: Это понятно, но этот код можно запустить что в основном, что в новом домене. В каком вы запускаете? Что даёт `AppDomain.CurrentDomain` в строчке перед `AppDomain.Unload`?